# How to POST an Object using Volley StringRequest

Tags: android-volley

I have 2 classes Order.java and OrderedItems.java as below:

```
public class Order {

private boolean IsScheduled;
private List<OrderedItems> OrderedItems;

public boolean isScheduled() {
    return IsScheduled;
}

public void setScheduled(boolean scheduled) {
    IsScheduled = scheduled;
}

public List<OrderedItems> getOrderedItems() {
    return OrderedItems;
}

public void setOrderedItems(List<OrderedItems> orderedItems) {
    OrderedItems = orderedItems;
}
```

}

```
public class OrderedItems {

private int ItemId;
private int Quantity;

public OrderedItems(int itemId, int quantity) {
    ItemId = itemId;
    Quantity = quantity;
}

public int getItemId() {
    return ItemId;
}

public void setItemId(int itemId) {
    ItemId = itemId;
}

public int getQuantity() {
    return Quantity;
}

public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
    Quantity = quantity;
}
```

}

I want to POST the below object in an appropriate format using Android Volley StringRequest to my Endpoint:

```
params.put("IsScheduled", "False");

params.put("OrderedItems[0].ItemId","1" );
params.put("OrderedItems[0].Quantity", "6");

params.put("OrderedItems[1].ItemId", "2");
params.put("OrderedItems[1].Quantity", "5");

params.put("OrderedItems[2].ItemId", "3");
params.put("OrderedItems[2].Quantity", "2");

Log.d(TAG, "getParams: " + order.toString());

params.put("OrderDTO",order.toString());

return params;
```

}

This is my WEB API Endpoint:

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult PlaceOrder(OrderDTO dto) 
{...}
```

and OrderDTO is:

```
public class OrderDTO
{
    public bool IsScheduled { get; set; }

    public List<OrderedItemsDTO> OrderedItems{ get; set; }
}
```

I want to send an Order object rather then using OrderedItems[0] or OrderedItems[1...].
Can i achieve it?